# How do I make sure that after shuffling a list, all values have actually changed index? (Python3.6)

Tags: python, list, random

The aim of my script is to create a list of progressive numbers:

```
examplelst=list(range(5))
```

Then, after importing random and shuffle, I want to randomise the list:

```
shuffle(examplelst)
```

Then I need to check if a value is still in its starting position, example:

```
before shuffling: [0,1,2,3,4]
after shuffling: [3,0,2*,4,1]
```

In this case, the value "2" still has index 2.
Should this happen, I want to shuffle again until I get every index changed randomly.
My approach so far:

```
done=False
shuffle(examplelst)

while not done:
    for i in examplelst:
        if examplelst[i]==int(i):
            shuffle(examplelst)
            print ('shuffled')
        else:
            done=True
if done == True:
    continue with my stuff knowing that the list is properly shuffled
```

I thought this would work but I'm wrong.
Anyone able to help?

Comment: You could shuffle with numbers, and use these numbers as indices for your old list? In that way you are always sure that your indices are shuffled randomly.

Comment: Why is it important that every item has moved? It doesn't make it un-random when this happens.

Comment: For a truly random shuffle there's a high probability that some elements will *not* be moved.  If you never see any values remain stationary then the shuffle is provably non-uniform.

Comment: `for i in list` in python iterates over list element, not list indices. You could use `enumerate`

Comment: @FlyInTheLotion: that would still not guarantee that numbers are moved. Replacing the values with placeholders (indices), doesn't change where they end up.

Comment: @TheEspinosa that was indeed a rookie mistake, I'm using `enumerate` now but still I'm not getting there.

Comment: @GeoffReedy It is important for my script, basically I need to shuffle until every number is in a position different from the starting one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you think that my answer fits the requirements - using `all()`?

Comment: If you guarantee that every element moves every time you shuffle, then your shuffle isn't properly random.

Comment: A shuffle the guarantees to move every element is called [Sattolo's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sattolo.27s_algorithm). It's a trivial modification on Fisher-Yates, and you don't have test and repeat to make sure you got it right. Wikipedia had sample code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you mixed index with list item and iterate over a list while modifying it.

```
done = False
while not done:
    if not next((item for i, item in enumerate(examplelst) if i == item), None):
        done = True
    else:
        shuffle(examplelst)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I took a different approach that I am sure is not elegant at all but at least it works.
I setup an internal counter that ticks up if the index if different from the value.
If the internal counter reaches the total number I have, this means that it's good to go. Otherwise after tot iteration it shuffles again e restarts.

```
done=False

while not done:
    shuffle(examplelst)
    intcount=0
    for i, item in enumerate(examplelst):
        #print (i, item)
        if i != item:
            intcount=intcount+1
            print (intcount)
            if intcount == total:
                done=True
        else:
            shuffle(examplelst)
if done == True:
    continue with my stuff knowing that the list is properly shuffled
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work as it takes advantage of the fact that `examplelst` is created through the `range` function. If you used an `examplelst` such as `[6, 7, 3, 1, 2]` then the `while` will never end.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I am aware that it's not a proper solution for other people with different setups, but it works for me so I thought I'd share it.

Comment: I completely understand, but for the sake of the site (which has an emphasis on the use for future readers) it is worth accepting a more general answer. **:)**

Answer (score 0):

The answer you posted to your own problem doesn't work as it compares the elements to the indexes of that element in the `list`. So when you are testing if `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` has been shuffled it works as you are generating the `exampleList` with `range` starting at `0`.

However, if you started with any other `list`, your solution wouldn't work for the reason stated above.

To get it to work, you need to make a copy of the original `list` so you have that as a reference for what has changed.

Then, whilst any element is at the same position, you need to keep shuffling.

Simple as that, here's the code:

```
import random
lst = list(range(5))
shfld = lst[:]
while any(lst[i] == shfld[i] for i in range(len(lst))):
    random.shuffle(shfld)
```

which when I ran it `3` times gave me these three results for `shfld`:

```
[1, 0, 3, 4, 2]

[1, 3, 4, 0, 2]

[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
```

which are all valid!